# A Bengali novel about Cricket

Tags: identification-request, bengali-language

I am trying to find a Bengali novel about cricket. I think I read it in the last 22 years, but it could have been published at the end of last century. As far as I can recall, I think I read it in an annual magazine.

The name of the main protagonist is Dipu (or Dilu). He is an exceptional fielder.
He is not a very good student.

The story ends with his mother agreeing to fund his sports equipment after a very successful match performance.

Comment: Hi erik and welcome to Lit SE. Thanks for the interesting question. There's a lot of good info in your question already, but could you scan the [tag identification wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and see if you can add anything else? Also, do you mean the story is in the Bengali language, or set in the general region of Bengal (Bangladesh, the state of West Bengal, etc)?